# resizableImageWithCapInsets inside NSTableView (view based)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecellview

i try to do resizableImageWithCapInsets (as in iOS) for mac.

```
    // right bubble
    NSLog(@"==================== OLD VALUES ==============");
    NSLog(@"size->%@",NSStringFromSize(size));
    NSLog(@"cellView.frame->%@",NSStringFromRect(cellView.frame));

    NSLog(@"message.frame->%@",NSStringFromRect(cellView.message.frame));
    NSLog(@"background.frame->%@",NSStringFromRect(cellView.background.frame));

    cellView.background.frame =  CGRectMake(cellView.frame.size.width - size.width,
                                            - size.height + cellView.date.frame.size.height * 1.8, size.width, size.height);


    necessaryBackgroundImage = [[NSImage imageNamed:@"OutgoingMessageBuble.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:15];

    cellView.message.frame = CGRectMake(cellView.frame.size.width - size.width,
                                        - size.height + cellView.date.frame.size.height * 1.8, size.width, size.height);

    NSLog(@"==================== NEW VALUES ==============");
    NSLog(@"message.frame->%@",NSStringFromRect(cellView.message.frame));
    NSLog(@"background.frame->%@",NSStringFromRect(cellView.background.frame));
    NSLog(@"necessaryBackgroundImage.size->%@",NSStringFromSize(necessaryBackgroundImage.size));
   cellView.background.image = necessaryBackgroundImage;
```

i do try NSImage subclass from here:
https://github.com/beefon/Mac---Stretchable-NSImage/blob/master/README

but it is not success:

[image]

a class allways return image with wrong size:

```
> 2012-11-22 01:02:30.009[37363:303] necessaryBackgroundImage.size->{43,
> 32} 2012-11-22 01:02:30.004[37363:303]
> necessaryBackgroundImage.size->{43, 32}
```

i expect image with size as necessary frame:

```
> 2012-11-22 01:02:30.003[37363:303] background.frame->{{50.6875,
> -115.19999999999999}, {265.3125, 162}}
```

Please can u explain, where is i'm wrong? Code snippet appreciated, i understand, that i must using NSDrawNinePartImage, but better is avoid long way. What i find also, that drawInRect of subclassed NSImage not called anywhere, and i don't know how i can push it.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: don't remember for now, but everything working fine )

Answer (score 0):

Stretchable-NSImage did't change the image, but rewrite the `drawRect`